# creating a column in pandas based on a unique condition of column matching

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a pandas dataframe, where I have sorted the dataframe based on date and time, hour, minute values.

This is the dataframe.

```
Date    year    month   day hour    minute  second  T   TM  Tm  ... PP  VV  V   VM  Latitude    Longitude   Peak Current (kA)   cluster_label   distances   time_differences
0   2011-05-10  2011    5   10  7   20  15  26.1    31.0    24.0    ... NaN 10.6    2.6 7.6 1.366675    103.587082  -49 0   5.01    25
1   2011-05-10  2011    5   10  7   22  15  26.1    31.0    24.0    ... NaN 10.6    2.6 7.6 1.360945    103.585228  -37 0   20.92   49
2   2011-05-10  2011    5   10  7   23  38  26.1    31.0    24.0    ... NaN 10.6    2.6 7.6 1.419045    103.616768  -11 0   1.21    59
3   2011-05-10  2011    5   10  7   24  33  26.1    31.0    24.0    ... NaN 10.6    2.6 7.6 1.389240    103.639519  -16 0   7.06    59
4   2011-05-10  2011    5   10  7   24  33  26.1    31.0    24.0    ... NaN 10.6    2.6 7.6 1.380240    103.645676  -16 0   21.58   2
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
529330  2018-12-31  2018    12  31  17  30  52  26.9    33.0    24.0    ... 1.52    10.0    5.7 16.5    1.403837    103.969101  -12 0   3.46    59
529331  2018-12-31  2018    12  31  17  30  52  26.9    33.0    24.0    ... 1.52    10.0    5.7 16.5    1.398877    103.993431  -9  0   3.84    59
529332  2018-12-31  2018    12  31  17  30  52  26.9    33.0    24.0    ... 1.52    10.0    5.7 16.5    1.416858    103.968040  -9  0   1.16    59
529333  2018-12-31  2018    12  31  17  30  52  26.9    33.0    24.0    ... 1.52    10.0    5.7 16.5    1.391595    103.991676  -13 0   1.93    57
529334  2018-12-31  2018    12  31  17  32  54  26.9    33.0    24.0    ... 1.52    10.0    5.7 16.5    1.401439    103.988052  -17 0   3.24    59
```

I want to create a new column, where the following conditions exists.

If
**1. year, 2. month, 3. day, 4. hour matches in for columns.**

the first observations of such type will be labelled as 0.

- the one where the **minute difference** with the first observation is
  in range 0-10 - labelled as 0-10
- the one where the **minute
  difference** with the first observation is in range 10-30 - labelled
  as 10-30
- the one where the **minute difference** with the first
  observation is in range 30-60 - labelled as 30-60

Comment: Please also include attempted code, to show your effort and approch.

Comment: print your output

Answer (score 0):

```python
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '2011-05-10', 1: '2011-05-10', 2: '2011-05-10', 3: '2011-05-10', 4: '2011-05-10', 5: '2018-12-31', 6: '2018-12-31', 7: '2018-12-31', 8: '2018-12-31'}, 'year': {0: 2011, 1: 2011, 2: 2011, 3: 2011, 4: 2011, 5: 2018, 6: 2018, 7: 2018, 8: 2018}, 'month': {0: 5, 1: 5, 2: 5, 3: 5, 4: 5, 5: 12, 6: 12, 7: 12, 8: 12}, 'day': {0: 10, 1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10, 4: 10, 5: 31, 6: 31, 7: 31, 8: 31}, 'hour': {0: 7, 1: 7, 2: 7, 3: 7, 4: 7, 5: 17, 6: 17, 7: 17, 8: 17}, 'minute': {0: 20, 1: 22, 2: 23, 3: 24, 4: 24, 5: 30, 6: 30, 7: 30, 8: 30}, 'second': {0: 15, 1: 15, 2: 38, 3: 33, 4: 33, 5: 52, 6: 52, 7: 52, 8: 52}, 'T': {0: 26.1, 1: 26.1, 2: 26.1, 3: 26.1, 4: 26.1, 5: 26.9, 6: 26.9, 7: 26.9, 8: 26.9}, 'TM': {0: 31.0, 1: 31.0, 2: 31.0, 3: 31.0, 4: 31.0, 5: 33.0, 6: 33.0, 7: 33.0, 8: 33.0}, 'Tm': {0: 24.0, 1: 24.0, 2: 24.0, 3: 24.0, 4: 24.0, 5: 24.0, 6: 24.0, 7: 24.0, 8: 24.0}, 'VV': {0: 10.6, 1: 10.6, 2: 10.6, 3: 10.6, 4: 10.6, 5: 1.52, 6: 1.52, 7: 1.52, 8: 1.52}, 'V': {0: 2.6, 1: 2.6, 2: 2.6, 3: 2.6, 4: 2.6, 5: 10.0, 6: 10.0, 7: 10.0, 8: 10.0}, 'VM': {0: 7.6, 1: 7.6, 2: 7.6, 3: 7.6, 4: 7.6, 5: 5.7, 6: 5.7, 7: 5.7, 8: 5.7}, 'Latitude': {0: 1.366675, 1: 1.360945, 2: 1.4190450000000001, 3: 1.38924, 4: 1.38024, 5: 1.403837, 6: 1.3988770000000001, 7: 1.416858, 8: 1.3915950000000001}, 'Longitude': {0: 103.587082, 1: 103.585228, 2: 103.61676800000001, 3: 103.63951899999999, 4: 103.645676, 5: 103.969101, 6: 103.993431, 7: 103.96804, 8: 103.991676}, 'Peak_Current_(kA)': {0: '-49', 1: '-37', 2: '-11', 3: '-16', 4: '-16', 5: '-12 0', 6: '-9', 7: '-9', 8: '-13 0'}, 'cluster_label': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 3.46, 6: 0.0, 7: 0.0, 8: 1.93}, 'distances': {0: 5.01, 1: 0.92, 2: 1.21, 3: 7.06, 4: 1.58, 5: 59.0, 6: 3.84, 7: 1.16, 8: 57.0}, 'time_differences': {0: 25.0, 1: 49.0, 2: 59.0, 3: 59.0, 4: 2.0, 5: nan, 6: 59.0, 7: 59.0, 8: nan}})
df = df[df.time_differences.notna()] # rows with nan values in time_diffrences are dropped
```

df:

```
         Date  year  month  day  hour  minute  second     T    TM    Tm     VV     V   VM  Latitude   Longitude Peak_Current_(kA)  cluster_label  distances  time_differences
0  2011-05-10  2011      5   10     7      20      15  26.1  31.0  24.0  10.60   2.6  7.6  1.366675  103.587082               -49            0.0       5.01              25.0
1  2011-05-10  2011      5   10     7      22      15  26.1  31.0  24.0  10.60   2.6  7.6  1.360945  103.585228               -37            0.0       0.92              49.0
2  2011-05-10  2011      5   10     7      23      38  26.1  31.0  24.0  10.60   2.6  7.6  1.419045  103.616768               -11            0.0       1.21              59.0
3  2011-05-10  2011      5   10     7      24      33  26.1  31.0  24.0  10.60   2.6  7.6  1.389240  103.639519               -16            0.0       7.06              59.0
4  2011-05-10  2011      5   10     7      24      33  26.1  31.0  24.0  10.60   2.6  7.6  1.380240  103.645676               -16            0.0       1.58               2.0
6  2018-12-31  2018     12   31    17      30      52  26.9  33.0  24.0   1.52  10.0  5.7  1.398877  103.993431                -9            0.0       3.84              59.0
7  2018-12-31  2018     12   31    17      30      52  26.9  33.0  24.0   1.52  10.0  5.7  1.416858  103.968040                -9            0.0       1.16              59.0
```

```
df['New_columns'] = ''
ind_ = df[['year', 'month', 'day']].drop_duplicates(keep="first").index.to_list()
df.loc[ind_, 'New_columns'] = '0'
```

df:

```
         Date  year  month  day  hour  minute  second     T    TM    Tm     VV     V   VM  Latitude   Longitude Peak_Current_(kA)  cluster_label  distances  time_differences New_columns
0  2011-05-10  2011      5   10     7      20      15  26.1  31.0  24.0  10.60   2.6  7.6  1.366675  103.587082               -49            0.0       5.01              25.0           0
1  2011-05-10  2011      5   10     7      22      15  26.1  31.0  24.0  10.60   2.6  7.6  1.360945  103.585228               -37            0.0       0.92              49.0            
2  2011-05-10  2011      5   10     7      23      38  26.1  31.0  24.0  10.60   2.6  7.6  1.419045  103.616768               -11            0.0       1.21              59.0            
3  2011-05-10  2011      5   10     7      24      33  26.1  31.0  24.0  10.60   2.6  7.6  1.389240  103.639519               -16            0.0       7.06              59.0            
4  2011-05-10  2011      5   10     7      24      33  26.1  31.0  24.0  10.60   2.6  7.6  1.380240  103.645676               -16            0.0       1.58               2.0            
6  2018-12-31  2018     12   31    17      30      52  26.9  33.0  24.0   1.52  10.0  5.7  1.398877  103.993431                -9            0.0       3.84              59.0           0
7  2018-12-31  2018     12   31    17      30      52  26.9  33.0  24.0   1.52  10.0  5.7  1.416858  103.968040                -9            0.0       1.16              59.0
```

```
def func_ (x):
    x = abs(x)
    if (x > 0) and (x <= 10): 
        return '0-10'
    elif (x>10) and (x <= 30): 
        return '10-30'
    elif (x>30) and (x <= 60) : 
        return '30-60'
    else: return None

DFs = []
ind_ = ind_+[len(df)]
for e,i in enumerate(ind_[:-1]):
    M = df.iloc[ind_[e] : ind_[e+1]]
    if len(M) > 1:
        f = (M.time_differences[1:] - M.time_differences[0]).apply(func_)
        f.index = M.index[1:]
        M['New_columns'] = ['0'] + f.to_list()
    else:
        M['New_columns'] = ['0']
    DFs.append(M)
df = pd.concat(DFs)
```

df:

```
         Date  year  month  day  hour  minute  second     T    TM    Tm     VV     V   VM  Latitude   Longitude Peak_Current_(kA)  cluster_label  distances  time_differences New_columns
0  2011-05-10  2011      5   10     7      20      15  26.1  31.0  24.0  10.60   2.6  7.6  1.366675  103.587082               -49            0.0       5.01              25.0           0
1  2011-05-10  2011      5   10     7      22      15  26.1  31.0  24.0  10.60   2.6  7.6  1.360945  103.585228               -37            0.0       0.92              49.0       10-30
2  2011-05-10  2011      5   10     7      23      38  26.1  31.0  24.0  10.60   2.6  7.6  1.419045  103.616768               -11            0.0       1.21              59.0       30-60
3  2011-05-10  2011      5   10     7      24      33  26.1  31.0  24.0  10.60   2.6  7.6  1.389240  103.639519               -16            0.0       7.06              59.0       30-60
4  2011-05-10  2011      5   10     7      24      33  26.1  31.0  24.0  10.60   2.6  7.6  1.380240  103.645676               -16            0.0       1.58               2.0       10-30
6  2018-12-31  2018     12   31    17      30      52  26.9  33.0  24.0   1.52  10.0  5.7  1.398877  103.993431                -9            0.0       3.84              59.0       30-60
7  2018-12-31  2018     12   31    17      30      52  26.9  33.0  24.0   1.52  10.0  5.7  1.416858  103.968040                -9            0.0       1.16              59.0           0
```